# How can I bring my IBM T60 out of sleep mode?

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, hibernate, sp3, thinkpad

My IBM [Thinkpad T60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad#ThinkPad_T60_series) goes into sleep (or hibernation?), and I cannot wake it up, no matter what keys I press. This includes pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> (blue key in the lower left of the keyboard) plus <kbd>F4</kbd> (with the half moon). The only method I've found is to do a hard reset, and this causes other problems. Is there another way?

Platform: Windows XP Professional SP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bring the laptop out of sleep by clicking the keyboard, since it's disconnected at that state. Have you tried pressing the power button? Short press only (long press will cause a full shutdown).

Comment: Well, I've just disconnected any sleep mode and no problem.

I'm going to give one an upvote and the other the acceptance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a possibility, but it can relate to a bad PSU or motherboard. Both need to enter a specific power state in order to recover from sleep/hibernation.